# UICollectionView vertically align sections and cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Is it possible to vertically align the sections and cells in a UICollectionView as in this picture: (Don't mind the center align of the cells!)

[image: align-vertically]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help you. You can have first line as one section and second line as next section.
And to get the different spacing between cell in a section, override collection view layout attributes and set the frame as you wish.